# I want to make visible a button for a specific role, role is under Opportunity Team

Tags: button, commandbutton, visibility

I want to make visible a button for a specific role, role is under Opportunity Team.

Detail:

I have an Oppo Team Member with role XYZ.
When i create a quote from opportunity, there is a custom Button 'B1' on quote detail page.
I want that Only the user under oppo team member with Role '**XYZ**' should be able to see that button '**B1**'

How to achieve this?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Use different page layouts for set of users. @Radhe Shyam

Comment: What kind of button is it? `Visualforce`? `Javascript`? Custom URL?